# what is a candidate row in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, row

What is a candidate row when talking about Oracle and SQL? Using it in a sentence would be as such:

"The candidate row is fetched from the table specified in the outer query."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A candidate row is a row from a table or subquery that could potentially be returned in the result set. To actually be returned it must satisfiy the WHERE and JOIN conditions.